# Lightning Lure / Falling Damage Question

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, initiative, environmental-hazards

So I'm playing a Variant Tiefling from the SCAG, and I took the Winged trait. I also took the Lightning Lure cantrip, so that I could combine LL's 1d8 lightning damage with the 1d6 bludgeoning damage falling. Now with the background out of the way, my question is this:

When would the creature fall? Would it fall immediately after my turn, or would it hang in the air until its turn?

Comment: Which creature?  Are you referring to the target of an attack, or your character?